# cannot prepare bundled jvm to run the installer netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7

I downloaded the jdk and netbeans am trying to install it 
but the error appears to me

> cannot prepare bundled jvm to run the installer

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Always check version of downloaded installer. If you have x64 system, and your installer is dedicated for x86 systems you will also see this error.

```
Cannot prepare bundled JVM to run the installer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203431 (you should install ia32-libs, if you have Ubuntu/Debian)